# How to make objects comparable

Tags: java, generics

I have class, that contains different types and implements `Iterable<Object>` interface. But it is very important to me, that I can compare elements. I am aware, that I can not write something like: `Iterable<Object & Comparable<?>>`, so what should I do?

I have ensured, that every single element contained in class:

- Can not be `null`.
- Is comparable to same type elements.
- Is immutable. Well, at least part that I'm checking.

It's not that, I just want to compare elements, because I can do that with:

```
private static int hackCMP(Object val, Object val2)
        throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException,
        IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException {
    Method m = val.getClass().getMethod("compareTo", val.getClass());
    return (Integer) m.invoke(val, val2);
}
```

I want to pass elements as input to another class indirect constructor, that also ensures elements need to be comparable. This method is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<?>> Os of(final Iterator<T> values) {
```

Comment: `Iterable<Object & Comparable<?>>` actually you can. ;)

Comment: Why not simply change your signature to `Iterable<Comparable<?>>`?  You gain nothing by explicitly stating that your objects have to extend `Object`, since all objects do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave Costa makes the point above that you should really just be using `Iterator<Comparable<?>>` rather than have `Object` in there. Your type should be as specific as needed. If you have methods that expect `Comparable<?>`, then use it. Methods that accept Objects can take anything anyway, including `Comparable`
s.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<?>> Os of(final Iterator<T> values) {
```

Is that your question?

EDIT: If you want to assume the object are comparable, you can do this.

```
public static int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo((Compareable) o2);
}
```

Comment: No, that is not my question. `<T extends Object & Comparable<?>>` is same as `<T extends Comparable<?>>` (Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass.).

Comment: I believe there is asubtle difference for generics, but it escapes me. In any case, what is your question?

Comment: Well, if I know that all elements are comparable, but they are stored as objects. Then how to pass them to a method, that also assumes thy are comparable.

Comment: You would cast the object to Comparable and use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to use is `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

You need to have the second `T` in there, because when you have `T extends Comparable<?>`, that doesn't actually ensure that the type is comparable with itself. You might think that is silly, but it is perfectly possible for me to make a class `Foo implements Comparable<String>`, and therefore `Foo` objects are unable to compare with themselves. Without the second `T` in there, you would not be able to guarantee that the object compares with itself, and would have to either cast or use raw types or something unsafe to be able to pass it.

The `? super` is a little more subtle. It is required when you consider subclasses of Comparable classes. For example if `A implements Comparable<A>`, and `B extends A`, then automatically `B implements Comparable<A>` (`B` cannot `implement Comparable<B>` because it can only implement an interface once). So to allow `B` to work with your design, the parameter of `Comparable` should be `? super T` instead of just `T` to allow it to be a superclass of `T`.